# Merging shapefiles with same attributes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have two shapefiles, a.shp and b.shp, containing point features with the following attribute tables:

```
a
-
id    att1   att2
-----------------
1     1      1
2     2      2

b
-
id    att1   att2
-----------------
3     1      1
4     2      1
```

If I use Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Union to create a new shapefile ab.shp I end up having an attribute table like this:

```
id     att1    att2    id_2    att1_2   att2_2
----------------------------------------------
1      1       1       null    null     null
2      2       2       null    null     null
null   null    null    3       1        1
null   null    null    4       2        1
```

But what I would like to have (and how it is in ArcGIS Desktop) is the following:

```
id   att1  att2
---------------
1    1     1
2    2     2
3    1     1
4    2     1
```

The fields are all of the same type (QString). So what would be the right way to produce the desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how it is in arcgis'? You're looking for an Append type of function. There's a specific tool for that in ArcGIS, but depending on context Merge would get you a multi-point feature rather than separate point records. You don't want a Union, which is meant to *combine* attributes based on shared geometry. You could also start editing, copy the points from one shapefile, and paste them into the other.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Vector/Data management Tools/Merge Shapefiles to One. I did a quick test using the data you supplied above, and also some of my own data, and both times it seemed to achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic, if you have `gdal`, you can also merge any number of shapefiles as follows on the command line:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append ab.shp a.shp  -f "esri shapefile" -nln ab
ogr2ogr -update -append ab.shp b.shp  -f "esri shapefile" -nln ab
```